# Добавить кнопку в таблице Джанго администратора для отображения информации в шаблоне

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-admin

Мне нужно добавить кнопку для отображения информации в шаблоне

мой код:

**models.py**

```
class Worker (models.Model):
    name = models.CharField ('Name', max_length=30)
    surname = models.CharField ('Surname', max_length=30)

class Salary (models.Model):
    worker = models.ForeignKey(Worker)
    salary_uah = models.IntegerField ('Salary', max_length=5)
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$',home, name='home'),
    url(r'^add/$',add_worker, name='add'),
    url(r'^act/$',acts, name='act')
```

**views.py**

```
def acts (request, id):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return redirect('/admin/')

    worker = get_object_or_404(Worker, id=id)
    return render(request, 'zpapp/act.html', worker)
```

**admin.py**

```
@admin.register(Salary)
class SalaryAdmin (admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('worker', 'salary_uah', 'button')
    search_fields = ('worker', 'salary_uah')
    list_filter = ('worker', 'salary_uah')

    def button(self, obj):
        return '<a class="button" href="{}">Print</a>'.format(reverse('admin:zpapp_salary_act', args=[obj.id]))

    button.short_description = 'Actions'
    button.allow_tags = True
```

Когда я запускаю код, я получаю ошибку:

`NoReverseMatch at /admin/zpapp/salary/
Reverse for 'zpapp_salary_act' with arguments '(2,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в том, что вы не правильно указывайте url адрес для страницы в админке. Если вам нужно перейти на страницу объекта, используйте следующий адрес:

```
reverse('admin:{{ app_name }}_{{ model_name }}_change', args=(object.id,))
```

[Полное описание урлов админки](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#reversing-admin-urls)